# gantt chart python - how to load data from the file instead of manually writing projects

Tags: python, gantt-chart

can someone please help with Python-Gantt?
below is the code

```py
from datetime import date
import gantt

task1_project1 = gantt.Task(name='task1', start=date(2021, 1, 27), duration=13)
task2_project1 = gantt.Task(name='task2', start=date(2021, 2, 10), duration=8)
task3_project1 = gantt.Task(name='task3', start=date(2021, 2, 9), duration=5)
project_1 = gantt.Project(name='Project 1')

for task in [task1_project1, task2_project1, task3_project1]:
  project_1.add_task(task)

project_1.make_svg_for_tasks(
            filename='Project_1.svg', 
            today=date(2021, 1, 27), 
            start=date(2021,1, 20),
            end=date(2021, 4, 1)
           )
```

can someone give example how to load data from the file? instead of writing each project manually ( like above).(1 project can have multiple tasks)
Hier is example of scv file:

```
Project         Task          Start          Duration (days)
Project1        TaskA      12.03.2021          5 
Project1        TaskB      15.03.2021         10
Project2        TaskA      20.05.2021         20
```

THX!

Comment: Have you tried using built-in CSV module? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)